# MS Release Management job fails due to error when Delete Files or Folder component executes

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ms-release-management

I'm using MS Release Management 2015 to do Agent based releases.  Most jobs involve deploying a web site or a windows service.  The typical pattern is to stop the site/app pool or service, deleted the folder for the site/service, deploy the new code, and restart the site or service.

The problem is that on roughly 40% of the release jobs, the component (the builtin ManageWindowsIO.ps1) that deletes the files/folders, fails.  It appears that sometimes this is because the service hasn't finished shutting down.  Sometimes the files/folders are actually deleted and the script reported a failure anyway.

Is there any workaround for this component or some way to make it more reliable?  In some cases, it might help if I could have the workflow pause for 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've hit the same thing several times and always just create a custom action called "Wait" that uses PowerShell to call `Start-Sleep` with a configurable delay in seconds.